# Probability of 3 events when 2 events are mutually exclusive

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

C.  Let $S$ represent the sample space of classrooms on UIC’s campus. Events are defined as follows:

$A$ = classroom remodeled/built within the last $5$ years

$B$ = classroom with a window(s)

$C$ = classroom without a projector

The following probabilities are known: $\textbf{P}(A) = 0.1$, $\textbf{P}(B) = 0.6$, $\textbf{P}(C) = 0.3$,
$\textbf{P}(A\cap B) = 0.1$, $\textbf{P}(A\cap C) = 0$ and $\textbf{P}(B\cap C) = 0.2$.

i.  Compute the probability $\textbf{P}(A\cap B\cap C)$.

ii. Compute the probability $\textbf{P}(A\cup B\cup C)$.

iii. Provide evidence, using the rules of probability, that you cannot find a classroom remodeled/built within the last $5$ years that doesn’t have a window.

For part i. Am i right to assume the formula is  $\textbf{P}(A)\textbf{P}(B|A)\textbf{P}(C|A\cap B)$ if i am not mistaken. If so can someone show me how to figure out this part of the formula $\textbf{P}(C|A\cap B)$?

Comment: could you shed some light on to seeing what i am doing wrong?

Comment: No $A\cap B\cap C\subseteq A\cap C$ so if $P(A\cap C)=0,$ then also $P(A\cap B\cap C\subseteq A\cap C)=0$

Comment: what does ⊆ mean?

Comment: $\subseteq$ means "subset."

Comment: I would suggest you start by drawing a Venn diagram to see what's going on.

Comment: I did I knew it had to be 0 in a way but with the probability formulas I didn't know how to prove it.

Comment: So If i did my math right part ii. answer is 1.1 correct as  ( ∪  ∪ ) = P(A) + P(B) +P(C) - ( ∩ )  - ( ∩ ) - ( ∩ ) + 0 (the answer to the first part) am i correct? @saulspatz

Comment: Do a Venn diagram in which A and C have no area in common. Start by labeling the two overlap regions with their appropriate probabilities. Then you can find everything you need for the union of the three sets from there. Just add disjoint probabilities. // I see no need for conditional  probability. // The intersection of all three is contained in the intersection $A \cap C$ which you know to have 0 probability.